# start-stop-reset simple timer using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a code that looks like this

**JS**

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = setInterval("tictac()", 1000);

function tictac(){
    counter++;
    $("#clock").html(counter);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="clock">0</div>
<div id="buttons" class="clear">
    <button id="start">start</button>
    <button id="stop">stop</button>
    <button id="reset">reset</button>
</div>
```

How can I make use of the buttons to control the timer, start counting up when **start** button is pressed, stop counting when **stop** button is pressed and reset counter when **reset** button is pressed.

Can someone help?

I managed to do this

```
        $(document).ready(function($) {

            var timer = undefined;
            $('#start').on('click', function(){
                timer = window.setInterval('tictac()', 1000);
            });
            $('#pause').on('click', function(){
                window.clearInterval(timer);
            });
            $('#reset').on('click', function(){
                timer = window.clearInterval(timer);
            });

        });

        var counter = 0;
        function tictac(){
            counter++;
            $("#clock").html(counter);
        }
```

The start and the stop buttons do the work, but the reset won't work, can some one check what's wrong with the code? pretty please

Comment: why the **"timer = window.clearInterval(timer);"** won't do the job, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't pass the function inside quotes to setInterval() some browsers refuse to do that now.

Answer (score 7):

try http://jsfiddle.net/vishalgupta358/DkTWN/

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = null;

function tictac(){
    counter++;
    $("#clock").html(counter);
}

function reset()
{
clearInterval(timer);
    counter=0;
}
function startInterval()
{
timer= setInterval("tictac()", 1000);
}
function stopInterval()
{
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't mentioned, I would like to control the timer using jQuery selectors

Comment: bind the functions to the buttons on page load

Comment: This fiddle link is dead, Can you post another one please!!

Answer (score 1):

Nailed the solution

```
$('#reset').on('click', function(){
    counter = -1;
    tictac();
    window.clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `onclick` to your button. For example: `<button onclick="tictac()">`. For further explanation, you can see this [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/). There has a demo that will solve your problem. Also, you can view the source code.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I want to control the timer using jQuery selectors